# Doctrine2 returns the same results

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

I use doctrine2 with MariaDB and ZF2.
I have a very weird problem where returned values by doctrine are the same with methods find, findBy, findAll, query, etc...

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
   `catid` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
   `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `category` (`catid`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Animaux'),
(2, 'Assurance - Mutuelle'),
(3, 'Auto - Moto');
```

I use this script to generate the entities

```
./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping --namespace="Database\\Entity\\" --force  --from-database annotation ./module/Database/src/
./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:generate-entities ./module/Database/src/ --generate-annotations=true
```

In the controller, I execute this code

```
    /** @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager[] $categoriesObject */
    $categoriesObject = $this->getObjectManager()
        ->getRepository('Database\Entity\Category')
        ->findBy(array(), array('name' => 'ASC'));

    $categories = array();
    /** @var \Database\Entity\Category $value */
    foreach($categoriesObject as $value) {
        print_r($value);
        $categories[$value->getCatid()] = $value->getName();
    }
    $form->get('category')->setValueOptions($categories);
```

And for information, the Category class generated by doctrine

```
<?php

namespace Database\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="catid", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $catid;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;



    /**
     * Get catid
     *
    * @return boolean
     */
    public function getCatid()
    {
        return $this->catid;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

With this code, when I execute the request, I get the following result :

> Database\Entity\Category Object
>   (
>       [catid:Database\Entity\Category:private] => 1
>       [name:Database\Entity\Category:private] => Animaux
>   )
>   Database\Entity\Category Object
>   (
>       [catid:Database\Entity\Category:private] => 1
>       [name:Database\Entity\Category:private] => Animaux
>   )
>   Database\Entity\Category Object
>   (
>       [catid:Database\Entity\Category:private] => 1
>       [name:Database\Entity\Category:private] => Animaux
>   )

Now, the weird thing is that if I remove the $catid field and the getCatid method from the class Category, I have the expected output and not the same row.

Do you have any ideas where the problem can come from ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time i looked at my question, I saw the problem.

Doctrine does not know the "tinyint" type, so it cast it in "boolean" when it generate entities -_-
So, I have to either convert my types to smallint, or manually modify on the generated entities.

Comment: Rubber duck debugging!